# Application specific mappings to a parent folder

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, lucee

I'm trying to create Application specific mappings to a parent folder. For some reason, this works on my local dev environment, I get the error

invalid component definition, can't find component [cfc.udf]

Directory structure:

```
--- website1
------- application.cfc

--- cfc
------ udf.cfc
```

Code on application.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent> 
    <cfset This.name = "Website1">
    <cfset This.Sessionmanagement=true>
    <cfset This.Sessiontimeout="#createtimespan(0,0,30,0)#">
    <cfset this.mappings["/cfc"] = expandPath('../cfc') />

    <cffunction name="onApplicationStart">
         <cfset Application.udf = createObject("cfc.udf")>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

I'm using Lucee 1.5

When I output the application, like so:

```
<cfset app = CreateObject("component",  "application") />
<cfdump var="#app#">
```

I get

```
MAPPINGS    
    Struct
        cfc string  D:\WebSites\parent-directory\cfc
```

I'm a bit lost

UPDATE:

in response to @leigh:

```
--- parent-directory
    --- website1
       --- application.cfc
    --- cfc
       --- udf.cfc
```

Comment: What is `parent-directory` in relation to your earlier "Directory structure:" example ?

Comment: @leigh: Please see above

Comment: When you do a `<cfdump var="#this.mappings#">` do you get the expected paths listed?

Comment: Yes, I get  cfc string  D:\WebSites\parent-directory\cfc

Comment: FWIW, what you posted works in ACF. I'll retest later with Lucee if you have not gotten an answer by then.

Comment: @leigh, you are a gentleman and a scholar! However the issue was in a different layer of the application altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it had nothing to do with Coldfusion or Lucee.

The problem was how we had the sites set up on IIS. We had to switch from IP + : + port to using a subdomain for this environment. So, tomkat was looking in the wrong context... Or at least that's what I was told. This is a bit outside the layer of abstraction that I'm most comfortable with.